# Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in wamp server 3.0 with oracle 10g running on windows 10

Tags: php, windows, oracle, oracle10g, wamp

I have a 64 bit Windows 10 PC, on which i want to install wamp server which is to be connected with oracle 10g. I have installed oracle 10g, oracle client for 10g. Also, i have downloaded the php_oci8.dll and copied it to ext/ directory of wamp. I also made the changes in the php.ini file i.e. added extension=php_oci8.dll. I have tried installing wamp server3.0 32 bit as well as 64 bit, yet i am not able to connect my php application with my database as it keeps on giving error message : "Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in line number 23". But i am able to connect to my database with sqldeveloper.

Any help....

Comment: Please try this: https://gist.github.com/odan/4edb46a44721f2ef3bdefe2ea999e2e8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by installing wamp 2.5 for 32 bit on windows 10 machine. It works fine with oracle 10g

Answer (score 1):

Use the Oracle 32-bit driver rather than the 64-bit. 
Configure PHP to work with the oracle client.

http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php